# Upadate ListView from adatpter when clicking an ImageButon

Tags: android, listview

I have List in a social networking app where i need to increase number of likes when user hits like button.[image]

The onclicklistener inside adapter and I am reloading the whole list which makes the list go to top when reloading and i have to make it stay at same post so that user keeps seeing same post not the top of list my adapter code is like this:

```
public class PaListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GroupPostValues> {

public PaListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView likeBtn = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.likeImage);

    likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // some asyncTask to call web servic that will increase likes

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

}
 .When I pass the position of this item through intent and reload the fragment making list  lv.setSelectionFromTop(positionReceivedFromIntent, 0); this is not reaching the same post, I am doing right?

Comment: like come from webservice are local database

Comment: clear list and load asyncTask and that update adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged().

Try below code:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

public LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<ListData> listObjects;

public Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<ListData> objects) {

    super();
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.listObjects = objects;

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTotalLikes, tvLike;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder vHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        vHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        vHolder.tvTotalLikes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalLikes);
        vHolder.tvLike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLike);

        convertView.setTag(vHolder);

        vHolder.tvLike.setTag(listObjects.get(position));

        vHolder.tvLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ListData data = (ListData) v.getTag();

                 if(!data.isAlreadyLiked()){
                    data.setLikes(data.getLikes() + 1);
                    data.setAlreadyLiked(true);
                    vHolder.tvTotalLikes.setText("" + data.getLikes());
                  }
            }
        });

    } else {
        vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        vHolder.tvLike.setTag(listObjects.get(position));

    }
    vHolder.tvTotalLikes.setText("" + listObjects.get(position).getLikes());

    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {

    return listObjects.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return listObjects.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

Comment: your code is great but looks like it will keep on increasing likes even if the user has already liked the post

Comment: See it is an sample code and you can change it according to your need like you can take like as boolean variable in model class and can check weather it is true or false inside button click.

Comment: vHolder.tvLike.setTag(listObjects.get(position));   vHolder.tvTotalLikes.setText("" + listObjects.get(position).getLikes()); what are these line for plase tell me.. its not working

Comment: You are using ArrayAdapter but my code is based on BaseAdapter in which i have pass an list of objects which i want to display on listview. listObjects is that list.

Comment: and this line vHolder.tvLike.setTag(listObjects.get(position)); is for setting model object for that particular row so that i can get exactly same values inside onClick

Comment: and this line vHolder.tvTotalLikes.setText("" + listObjects.get(position).getLikes()); is setting total number of likes on textview

Comment: Thanks man it took time but i implemented your logic thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Change the getView method. add `notifyDataSetChanged();` to your `onClick` method:
do not update list or refresh UI manualy.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

...
likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // some asyncTask to call web servic that will increase likes
        ...
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
...
```